# Unpack Existentials in Existential Type

Tags: haskell, types, gadt, existential-type

I tried to write the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module V where

data V a where
  V :: (c -> a) -> V a

down :: V (V a) -> V a
down (V f) = V $ \(c,d) -> case f c of
  V f' -> f' d
```

Then GHC answered `` type variable `c' would escape its scope ``.

I understand why it doesn't compile: it uses hidden type of existential **out of `case`**.

But actually the type is still **hidden** by `V`. so essentially function `down` has no problem I think.

Is there a way to write a compilable `down` function?

Comment: there a certain type what `f'` accepts. I expect `d` to be such a type, so it looks no problem. especially `undefined`-ness is not concerned because `V :: (c -> (c,a)) -> V a` will cause the same, in spite of it accepts a sane value `\y -> (y,x)` for `x :: a`.

Comment: If you have some kind of extra constraints in your GADT, which _might_ allow this to be written, you should add them to the question.

Comment: in fact my original case was `V :: (c -> (c,a)) -> V a`, but the essential point is not 
changed by simplication. so if the simplified code was prohibited, then original case must be prohibited.

Comment: ah, `\y -> (y,x)` wasn't correct response... `\f -> let (x,c) = f c in x` is.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `f'` can be applied `d`, so it's not just a matter of the type remaining hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the fundamental problem: `f` can have a peek at `c` and use the value of `c` to determine which type to hide in its existential. For example:

```
v :: V (V Int)
v = V $ \p -> case p of
     False -> V (id :: Int -> Int)
     True  -> V (fromEnum :: Char -> Int)
```

So `d` would need to be both a valid `Int` and a valid `Char` if we called `down v`! To be able to feed an existential that can be so variable, you'll need to ensure that its argument can take on all the types it may demand.

```
newtype Forall = Forall (forall a. a)

down :: V (V a) -> V a
down (V f) = V $ \(c, d_) -> case f c of
    V f' -> case d_ of
        Forall d -> f' d
```

Comment: ah, your `v` example is perfect for me to understand... thanks!

Comment: In Coq, with full dependent types, I was able to define a (very messy) `down` without relying on such uninhabited type as `Forall`, instead requiring `(c,d_)` to be a dependent pair so that `d_` can be passed to `f'`. I'm not posting the code since it's autogenerated with tactics, hence it's unreadable. Still, it's interesting (for me at least) to know that it can be done.

Comment: I managed to find a clean solution in Coq, closer to the OP's code. We can't translate it in Haskell (can we?), but at least we can see how it could be done with full dependent types.

Comment: @chi You should be able to translate it to Haskell using singletons, may not be very pretty though

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, I can't find a simple way to make your code work.

I find it interesting though, that your idea does work in a language with full dependent types like Coq (and likely Agda, Idris, etc.).

The main crux, as Daniel Wagner points out, is that the type resulting from `f` can depend on the value of `c`, so the pair `(c,d)` in the original code should be a *dependent pair*.

For what it is worth, here's how we can do it in Coq.

Note that this does not involve an uninhabited type like `forall a. a`.

```
(* An existential type, under an impredicative encoding *)
Inductive V (A: Type): Type :=
  Vk : forall (B: Type), (B -> A) -> V A
.

(* The usual "identity to equivalence" *)
Definition subst {A B: Type} (p: A = B) (x: A): B :=
   match p with
   | eq_refl => x
   end .

(* The main function.

   Essentially, we want to turn
     Vk B (fun b => Vk C g)
   into
     Vk (B*C) (fun (b,c) => g c)
   but both C and g can depend on (b:B), so (B*C)
   should be a Sigma type {b:B & ty b}.

*)
Definition down (A: Type) (x: V (V A)): V A :=
   match x with
   | Vk B f => let
      ty (z: V A): Type := match z with | Vk C g => C end
      in Vk A {b:B & ty (f b)} (fun w =>
         match w with
         | existT b y =>
            match f b as o return ty (f b) = ty o-> A with
            | Vk C g => fun (h: ty (f b) = C) =>
               g (subst h y)
            end eq_refl
         end )
   end .
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for another great answer, chi!

I rewrote the code for Agda and actually it does compile. As an additional note for the above answer, I place my code here.

```
module down where

open import Level
open import Data.Product

data V {ℓ} (A : Set ℓ) : Set (suc ℓ) where
  Vk : {B : Set} → (B → A) → V A

down : ∀ {ℓ} {A : Set ℓ} → V (V A) → V A
down {ℓ} {A} (Vk {B} f) = Vk go where
  ty : V A → Set
  ty (Vk {C} _) = C
  go : Σ B (λ b → ty (f b)) → A
  go (b , c) with f b
  go (b , c) | Vk {C} g = g c
```